# About cache memory size - Getting the number of blocks out of the size and number words per block

Tags: caching, memory-management, architecture

This is an example from the book Computer Organization and Architecture by Stallings

- The cache can hold 64 Kbytes
- Data are transfered between main memory and the cache in blocks of 4 bytes each. This means that the cache is organized as 16K = 2^14 lines of 4 bytes each *.
- The main memory has 16M. That is 2^24 words. So 4M blocks of 4 bytes.

My confusion is in the second point. It is said that each block is of 4 bytes that is 4 words of 8 bits so one block is 32 bits = 2^5. Now I want to get the number of blocks in the cache. For that I divide the size of the cache with the size of one block, that is 2^16(64K)/2^5(4bytes) = 2^11 lines of 4 bytes each but the answer is 2^14. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its 64K Bytes so it will be 2^16 Bytes.

You will have to make it to bits so it will be (2^16 * 2^3 bits) / 2^5 bits = 2^14